# How to pass 3 argument to backend with `POST` request?

Tags: angular7, angular-httpclient

According to backend, I require to pass 3 argument through post request, this backend function is:

```
public ResponseModel Post([FromBody] CourseFileUpload item, string fileName, Stream fileToUpload)
```

now I am trying to pass the argument like this:

```
uploadFile(uploadData:ModelToFileSteam):Observable<ModelToFileSteam> {
        const fileName = uploadData.fileName;
        console.log('file name is', fileName);
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
        return this.http.post<ModelToFileSteam>(environment.baseUrl+`CourseFileUpload`, uploadData.fileToUpload, uploadData.fileName, uploadData.uploadStream)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                return data;
            } ),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }
```

But getting error, not able to pass 3 arguments at all. what is the correct way to do this?

any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest wrapping all in a single object. And send it to backend.

Or just send uploadData

```
return this.http.post<ModelToFileSteam>(environment.baseUrl+`CourseFileUpload`, uploadData)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                return data;
            } ),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
```

And in the backend, you can get uploadDate like `req.body.uploadData`
To check you can `console.log(uploadData.fileName);`

Answer (score 1):

its my working example

```
this.http.post<Customer>(this.base_url + 'v1/customers', client, this.getHeaders());
```

Where client is customer object and this.getHeaders() is:

```
  getHeaders() {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      })
    };
  }
```

Good luck!